# Unable to transfer NEAR tokens between accounts using near-api-js

Tags: next.js, nearprotocol, near-api-js

I am trying to transfer NEAR tokens between 2 testnet wallets using the near-api-js library in NextJS

Running send money function of the account, I am getting the following error

```
import { connect, keyStores } from "near-api-js";

export const NearConfig = async () => {
    const config = {
        networkId: "testnet",
        keyStore: new keyStores.BrowserLocalStorageKeyStore(),
        nodeUrl: "https://rpc.testnet.near.org",
        walletUrl: "https://wallet.testnet.near.org",
        helperUrl: "https://helper.testnet.near.org",
        explorerUrl: "https://explorer.testnet.near.org",
    };
    return await connect(config);
};


setNear(await NearConfig());

const sendTokens = async () => {
        try {
            const account = await near.account(account_id);

            await account.sendMoney(
                "itissandeep98.testnet", // receiver account
                "100000000" // amount in yoctoNEAR
            );
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            showAlert(error.message, "error");
        }
    };
```

[image]

On running `account.getAccessKeys();` there are full access keys as well as functional access keys available, then why I am not able to send tokens?

Moreover, I don't understand the below screenshot from the docs(https://docs.near.org/docs/develop/front-end/introduction); why isn't it allowed?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this after one week of struggle: [Connect FullAccess account with near-api-js](https://docs.antisociallabs.io/knowledge-base/connect-fullaccess-account-with-near-api-js)

```
const PENDING_ACCESS_KEY_PREFIX = "pending_key";

const loginFullAccess = async (options) => {
  const currentUrl = new URL(window.location.href);
  const newUrl = new URL(wallet._walletBaseUrl + "/login/");
    newUrl.searchParams.set('success_url', options.successUrl || currentUrl.href);
  newUrl.searchParams.set('failure_url', options.failureUrl || currentUrl.href);

  const accessKey = KeyPair.fromRandom("ed25519");
  newUrl.searchParams.set("public_key", accessKey.getPublicKey().toString());
  await wallet._keyStore.setKey(
    wallet._networkId,
    PENDING_ACCESS_KEY_PREFIX + accessKey.getPublicKey(),
    accessKey
  );

  window.location.assign(newUrl.toString());
};
```

After login you can use the `sendMoney` function to transfer NEAR tokens between accounts

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to open up near website asking user for permissions required for sending the tokens. Was struggling till I noticed this text in [nearjs doc](https://near.github.io/near-api-js/classes/account.Account/#sendmoney) regarding `account.sendMoney`:

> Hint
>
> Use WalletConnection in the browser to redirect to NEAR Wallet for
> Account/key management using the BrowserLocalStorageKeyStore.

Basically, instead of `nearConnection` needed to use `walletConnection`

```
    // const account = await nearConnection.account(accountId) // Wrong
    const account = await walletConnection.account() // Profit
```